# Swift Async Alamofire return

Tags: swift, asynchronous, alamofire

I'm getting an empty value on return annotations, I am sure this is because of the async scope, Ive tried everything to get

```
 var annotations: [TestAnnotation] = []
```

to return the values but I can't. The loop is correctly appending the values within the makeRequest scope.

```
func makeRequest(url : String, params : [String : String]?, completionHandler: (responseObject: JSON?, error: NSError?) -> ())  -> Request? {

    return Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: params, encoding: .URL)
        .responseString { request, response, responseBody, error in completionHandler(
            responseObject:
            {
                // JSON to return
                var json : JSON?
                if let response = responseBody {
                    // Parse the response to NSData
                    if let data = (response as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                        json = JSON(data: data)
                    }
                }

                return json

                }(), error: error)
    }
}

func annotations() -> [TestAnnotation] {
    var annotations: [TestAnnotation] = []

    var points: NSDictionary = [:]
    self.makeRequest("http://192.168.0.10/test/globe.php", params: nil) { json, error in

        if let data = json!.rawData() {
            let json = JSON(data: data)

            for var i = 0; i < json["venues"].count; i++
            {
                let lat = (json["venues"][i]["latitude"]).doubleValue as CLLocationDegrees
                let lon = (json["venues"][i]["longitude"]).doubleValue as CLLocationDegrees
                let venuesid = (json["venues"][i]["id"]).stringValue as String
                ///
                let coordinate1 : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)

                let a1: TestAnnotation = TestAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate1, title: glimpid)
                annotations.append(a1)

            }
        }

    }
    return annotations

}
```

Comment: The return value by annotations function is empty ?

Comment: yes, sorry if it wasn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply returning an empty array in your code, discarding the results and ignoring the errors received. If you want to return the result from the asynchronous call, you have to do it asynchronously too. Something like this:

```
func annotations(onComplete: (NSError?, [TestAnnotations]?) -> Void) {
    self.makeRequest("http://192.168.0.10/test/globe.php", params: nil) { json, error in

        var annotations: [TestAnnotations]?
        if let data = json!.rawData() {
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            annotations = [TestAnnotation]()

            for var i = 0; i < json["venues"].count; i++
            {
                let lat = (json["venues"][i]["latitude"]).doubleValue as CLLocationDegrees
                let lon = (json["venues"][i]["longitude"]).doubleValue as CLLocationDegrees
                let venuesid = (json["venues"][i]["id"]).stringValue as String
                ///
                let coordinate1 : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)

                let a1: TestAnnotation = TestAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate1, title: glimpid)
                annotations?.append(a1)

            }
        }

        onComplete(error, annotations)

    }
}
```

**EDIT**: There are many ways to call this method, check the [Closures documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) to see how to pass your closure parameter. This is one of them:

```
self.annotations { error, annotations in 
    // Check for errors
    if let error = error {
        NSLog("Received error: %@", error)
    }
    if let annotations = annotations {
        // Do whatever you want with your received annotations, like saving as property and reloading a table view
        self.savedAnnotations = annotations
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: how could I call annotations now? What would be the parameters?

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: params, encoding: .URL)
        .responseString { request, response, responseBody, error in completionHandler(
            responseObject:
            {
                // JSON to return
                var json : JSON?
                if let response = responseBody {
                    // Parse the response to NSData
                    if let data = (response as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                        json = JSON(data: data)
                        self.annotations(json)
                    }
                }

                return json

                }(), error: error)
    }

func annotations(json : JSON) -> [TestAnnotation] {
    var annotations: [TestAnnotation] = []

    var points: NSDictionary = [:]

            for var i = 0; i < json["venues"].count; i++
            {
                let lat = (json["venues"][i]["latitude"]).doubleValue as CLLocationDegrees
                let lon = (json["venues"][i]["longitude"]).doubleValue as CLLocationDegrees
                let venuesid = (json["venues"][i]["id"]).stringValue as String
                ///
                let coordinate1 : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)

                let a1: TestAnnotation = TestAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate1, title: glimpid)
                annotations.append(a1)

            }

    }
    return annotations
}
```

I do not know if it will help you

NOTE : You are using Alamofire for the request and SwiftJSON to work easily, you can coupled by doing this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters)
  .responseJSON { (req, res, json, error) in
    if(error != nil) {
      NSLog("Error: \(error)")
      println(req)
      println(res)
    }
    else {
      NSLog("Success: \(url)")
      var json = JSON(json!)
    }
  }
```

[SwiftyJSON - Alamofire](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#work-with-alamofire)

Comment: You're still returning an empty array. The array won't be populated until the request is finished and the JSON is parsed, and you are returning the result way earlier to the caller.